# Help with the proof of the open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I don't understand the following from the proof of the open mapping theorem.

Suppose $A $  is a bounded linear transformation from the Banach space $X $ onto the Banach space $Y $.

Using Baire's category theorem we find an open set $W \subset \overline {A(kU)}   $, where $U $ is the unit ball centered at the origin in $X $. This says every element of $W $ is a limit point of $A(kU) $ .

Chose $y_0 \in W $ and $\eta >0$ such that $y _0 +y \in W $ if $||y ||< \eta $
Then there are sequences $\{x' _i \} $ and $\{x'' _i \} $ in $k U $ such that $A x ' _i \to y _0 $  and $A x'' _i \to y _0 + y $. Setting $x _i= x'' _i - x ' _i $ $A x _i \to y $. And $||x _i ||< 2k $ (implying $||x ||\le 2k $, right?)

---

Now it is claimed that "since this holds for every y with $||y ||< \eta $, the linearity of $A $ show that the following is true, if $\delta = \eta /2k $.

To each $y \in Y $ and to each $\epsilon >0 $ there corresponds an $x \in X $ such that

$$||x ||\le \delta ^{-1 } ||y || $$ and $$||y - Ax ||<\epsilon $$.

First $||x ||\le 2k $ but if $||y ||< \eta $ then $2k ||y ||/\eta < 2k$, so how does the first assertion follow?

Secondly how do we use the linearity of $A $ to extend the result of $||y-Ax ||< \epsilon $ from $W$, to all of $Y $?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the proof that you apparently understand (before "Now it is claimed" in your question) shows that every $y$ with $\Vert y\Vert<\eta$ is the limit of a sequence $Ax_i$ in the range of $A$, with $\Vert x_i\Vert\leq2k$ for all $i$.  Now suppose you want to approximate some $y$ whose norm is not known to be $<\eta$. Well, consider $y'=(\eta/2(\Vert y\Vert)y$; that is, shrink $y$ to a vector $y'$ in the same direction but with norm $<\eta$.  Then you can approximate $y'$ arbitrarily closely by vectors $Ax_i$ with $\Vert x_i\Vert\leq2k$.  By linearity of $A$ (and homogeneity of the norm) your original $y$ is approximable arbitrarily closely by vectors of the form $(2\Vert y\Vert/\eta)Ax_i$ (just enlarge the $x_i$'s to compensate for the shrinking you did to $y$).  These new approximating vectors are $\Vert y\Vert\cdot Az_i$ where $z_i=(2/\eta)x_i$ has norm at most $4k/\eta$.

(Note that, when I defined $y'$, I included a factor $2$ in the denominator to make sure the norm is strictly less than $\eta$.  Any factor $>1$ would have worked as well, so the $4$ in at the end of the preceding paragraph could be replaced by any factor $>2$.)

Comment: Your answer shows the existence of $x$ such that $\|x\| \leq ck / \eta \|y\|$ for all $c$ strictly greater than 2, but how does Rudin show $\|x\| \leq ck / \eta \|y\|$ with $c = 2$?

Comment: @yumiko There seem to be several ways to get $c=2$. Probably the simplest is to note that the earlier part of the proof didn't really need $\Vert y\Vert<\eta$; a non-strict inequality would suffice here. The point is that, since $W$ is included in the **closed** set $\overline{A(kU)}$, so is the closure of $W$, which includes the closed ball around $y_0$ of radius $\eta$. With this change in the first part of the proof, you can use my answer without the factor $2$ in the definition of $y'$.

Comment: I am not so sure about the part that "so is the closure of $W$", because Rudin writes on a previous page(pg 97) in the proof of the Baire's Theorem that that "note: There are situations in which the closure of the open ball with radius r does not equal the closed ball of radius $r$".

Comment: @yumiko The situation where the closure of an open ball is not the closed ball of the same radius does not arise when the metric space in question is a vector space (provided the radius of the ball is positive).

Comment: @yumiko Right. In a normed vector space, it suffices (by translation and scaling) to consider the open & closed balls of radius 1 around the origin. Then any vector $x$ in the closed ball is approached by vectors $(1-\frac1n)x$ in the open ball.  In contrast, the "bad" situations Rudin describes are missing such approximating points. The simplest example of such a situation is a two-point space with the distance between the two points being $1$. The open unit ball about one point contains only that point, and so does its closure, but the closed unit ball around one point contains both points.